# Is ed25519 well supported for the DKIM validation?

Tags: exim, gmail, dkim

Based on the `Exim4` [docs](https://exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-dkim_spf_srs_and_dmarc.html) I have the following script:

```
#! /bin/bash --

ED="dkim_ed25519_$(date +'%Y%m%d')"
RSA="dkim_rsa_$(date +'%Y%m%d')"

## Generate private key
openssl genpkey -algorithm ed25519 -out "${ED}.private"
openssl genrsa -out "${RSA}.private" 2048

## Use private key to generate the public DNS TXT record:
## 20200701._domainkey.example.com IN TXT "k=[ed25519|rsa]; p=[pub_key_content]"
openssl pkey -in "${ED}.private" -pubout -outform DER | tail -c +13 | base64 > "${ED}.public"
openssl rsa -in "${RSA}.private" -pubout -outform PEM | sed '/^-----/d' | tr -d '\n' > "${RSA}.public"
```

This generates a pair of private + public keys. Public ones are:

*dkim_ed25519_20200701.public*:

```
ICkF+6tTRKc8voK15Th4eTXMX3inp5jZwZSu4CH2FIc=
```

*dkim_rsa_20200701.public*:

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtZMwFIfqRCUPAp6Jz5OPC9GC68JWsVA5VF2RBGH8Bx7rIRE6vekhejwqK4rmiaMswfuJEMKErWE0ZwYz7bhSsBMnv0G1xC7OLgOTCziUO1EjMp/R5/aUno1Y0txFcJJdbSNEpZYc0jMLW3TqNn3VN6glVpnPId2Rb6SqfweS7zYp04LrX+pT43pCEn9pHxVOmWfmz8AJav1kuYM5KvU7gsC3ytzaxW+QlHTaWH9vGtgK1GVg0NGQmPS2/nLSDABjJPATDN/d3PagpsPdwGtOPfe4ShW32FBhRVL9X3ZeeUP4y1iZn0Si4sQiWYAfwekxLh2lsvALAHPc7er8RxJ4yQIDAQAB
```

When I've tried to plug in those into the domain's TXT records like so:

*RSA*:

```
k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtZMwFIfqRCUPAp6Jz5OPC9GC68JWsVA5VF2RBGH8Bx7rIRE6vekhejwqK4rmiaMswfuJEMKErWE0ZwYz7bhSsBMnv0G1xC7OLgOTCziUO1EjMp/R5/aUno1Y0txFcJJdbSNEpZYc0jMLW3TqNn3VN6glVpnPId2Rb6SqfweS7zYp04LrX+pT43pCEn9pHxVOmWfmz8AJav1kuYM5KvU7gsC3ytzaxW+QlHTaWH9vGtgK1GVg0NGQmPS2/nLSDABjJPATDN/d3PagpsPdwGtOPfe4ShW32FBhRVL9X3ZeeUP4y1iZn0Si4sQiWYAfwekxLh2lsvALAHPc7er8RxJ4yQIDAQAB
```

*ED25519*:

```
k=ed25519; p=ICkF+6tTRKc8voK15Th4eTXMX3inp5jZwZSu4CH2FIc=
```

I have figured that my DKIM `rsa` version works fine with `gmail`, but `ed25519` just fails.

Did I make a mistake in my code/config? Or is it the case that `ed25519` is not widely adopted?

Answer (score 6):

**As of 2022-01, not a single big mail provider regularly verifies ed25519 signatures**, though the reported result will not be consistent, I have seen in DMARC reports (along with `pass` for other signatures):

- `fail`
- `permerror`
- `temperror`
- `neutral`

Your configuration looks good to me, and should cause absolutely no issues **using it *supplementary to* 2048-bit RSA signatures**. I am sending one of each signature and that is also what everyone else adopting the new algorithm seems to be doing to test readiness for the transition.

All common software correctly parses the signature (so it can report the name) and ignores the signature algorithm it has yet to learn. I have still not received a single DMARC report from a public mail provider confirming any verified ed25519 signature.

My receiving experience continues to have more `rsa-sha1` signatures (less useful nowadays, should long be succeeded by `rsa-sha256`) than `ed25519-sha256` ones, but last year I saw the first EC ones from non-academic institutions, so adoption *may* finally be happening.

Comment: Any updates so far?

Comment: @RobertSiemer Microsoft, Yahoo, Google, still officially do not utilize them, and clearly say so in their aggregate reports. Fun fact: I have yet to fail verifying a received EC signature - seems only environments which get canonicalisation order right support the new algorithm (and: everyone using it double signs rsa+ed25519 anyway).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Still seems b0rked in almost-2024.